# XSLT: Specific Element Always Added to root?

Tags: xslt

I have a situation where particular elements (xs:simpleType, xs:complexType) are placed in the output as they are encountered:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="HighSchoolType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="OrganizationName" type="core:OrganizationNameType"/>
        <xs:element name="OPEID" type="core:OPEIDType"/>
        <xs:simpleType name="OPEIDType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="OrganizationNameType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

I'd prefer that the xs:simpleType always be attached to the root, no matter where the pattern is encountered in the source.  IE:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="HighSchoolType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="OrganizationName" type="core:OrganizationNameType"/>
        <xs:element name="OPEID" type="core:OPEIDType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="OrganizationNameType"/>
  <xs:simpleType name="OPEIDType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Is it possible to stop duplicates at this point as well?

Here's the template I'm currently using:

```
<xsl:template match="xs:simpleType">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::xs:annotation or self::xs:restriction)]|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:template match="/xs:schema">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="//xs:simpleType"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[name()!='xs:simpleType' and name()!='xs:schema']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: steamer25 - that works, thanks.  It looks like I'll have to run two xsl files to get my desired output.